# Driver for ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5650 on 15.10?

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, radeon, fglrx

I have a laptop with **2 GPUs**. ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5650 and Intel HD Graphics. *About this Computer* say under *Graphics*: *Intel® Ironlake Mobile*

I tried using the proprietary driver under *System Settings* -> *Software&Updates* -> *Additional Drivers*: from fglrx.

After a restart the System crashed it startet in **low graphic mode** The XServer gave me a fatal error.

Is there a way to install the Catalyst program under Ubuntu 15.10? And how? I did not find out.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the Catalyst Control Center by running:

`sudo apt-get install fglrx-amdcccle`

Once it's installed, run it from the terminal by typing `sudo amdcccle`

Comment: after runn ing those two commands I couldn't start The Catalyst Control Center.
I tried running the command `sudo aticonfig --initial` but after a restart the same fatal error again. Any solutions?

Comment: Any chance you could post the error messages?

Comment: I don't know where to find them. Only saw the error message when running the low-graphics mode.

Comment: After a bit of research I found out it seems to be a known issue with the linux 4.2 kernel... I found a solution but it didn't work for me, too.